# How to return only unique value from array objects bound to an element in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am very very new to `d3.js`. I have parent `g container` that looks like so

```
var g = pieParentG.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + xVal + "," + yVal + ")")
    .selectAll("arc")
    .data(pie(dataVal))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");
```

I am trying to add a child text node like so

```
 var textG = g.append("g")
     .append("text")
     .html(function(d) {
         return d.data.zone;
     });
```

However, the dataval array of objects might contain duplicate values. An example of the array is

```
[{
        "count": 1267,
        "path": 1,
        "zone": "Bandra-Pillers"
    },
    {
        "count": 697,
        "path": 2,
        "zone": "Bandra-Pillers"
    },
    {
        "count": 560,
        "path": 3,
        "zone": "Bandra-Pillers"
    }
]
```

the text field should map to this zone field in the array. In case of duplicate values, such as in this case, I want only 1 text element to be appended. Is the Array.filter function an option? If yes, then where do I use it?

Comment: you might consider to preprocess your dataval, how about filter() or reduce() them so you remove or recalculate the duplicates. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

> the text field should map to this zone field in the array. In case of duplicate values, such as in this case, I want only 1 text element to be appended. Is the Array.filter function an option? If yes, then where do I use it?

Actually if you want to return only 1 object matching this `zone` from your array, you can't use `.filetr()`as it will return alll the elements that have the same `zone`.

You can use **[`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** it will return only the first `object` that pass the condition:

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

This is how should be your code:

```
var myObj = dataVal.find(function(item) {
  return item.zone === "Bandra-Pillers";
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var dataVal = [{
    "count": 1267,
    "path": 1,
    "zone": "Bandra-Pillers"
  },
  {
    "count": 697,
    "path": 2,
    "zone": "Bandra-Pillers"
  },
  {
    "count": 560,
    "path": 3,
    "zone": "Bandra-Pillers"
  }
];

var myObj = dataVal.find(function(item) {
  return item.zone === "Bandra-Pillers";
});

console.log(myObj);
```

**Edit:**

You can call it in the callback function of `.html()` like this:

```
var textG = g.append("g")
     .append("text")
     .html(function(d) {
         return dataVal.filter(function(item){
              return item.zone === zone; //Pass zone variable here
         })[0].data.zone;
});
```

Comment: Where exactly do I need to add this snippet in the d3 code. I can find the unique values but I am looking for some clarity in adding this filter code in the right place to return only one text element with the zone name for the array i have written as an example

Comment: You need to call it in the `.html()` function call, see my Edit.

Comment: @SohamBhaumik Check it now.